# Fibonacci sequence: ruby each method - nil can't be coerced

Tags: ruby, indexing, each

I put together the following methods in order to (1) generate a Fibonacci sequence in an array up to a particular index value, and then (2) return the product of all values in that sequence for the given index.

My issues seems to come about when I increase the master_num value above 4. Prior to that both the sequence generating & product methods work. I'm pretty sure my problem is related to a mistake in my mind about how Ruby is indexing the sequence array...

```
require 'pry'  #optional, i use pry to debug

master_num = 5

def gen_fib_sequence_up_to_index num
  rec_gen_fib_values num, []
end

def rec_gen_fib_values num, full_array
  start_array = [1,1]
  count = 0

  if num < start_array.size
    num
  end

  until start_array.size == num
    next_element = start_array[count] + start_array[count + 1]
    start_array.push(next_element)
    count += 1
  end
  return start_array
end

p gen_fib_sequence_up_to_index master_num

def fib_sequence_product sequence_array
  product = 1
  sequence_array.each do |i|
    product = product * sequence_array[i]
    #binding.pry
  end
  product
end

p fib_sequence_product gen_fib_sequence_up_to_index master_num
```

Thanks so much for your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def fib_sequence_product sequence_array
  product = 1
  sequence_array.each do |i|
    product = product * sequence_array[i]
    #binding.pry
  end
  product
end
```

In the block `i` is not an index, it's the actual value. This should work:

```
def fib_sequence_product sequence_array
  product = 1
  sequence_array.each do |i|
    product = product * i # or product *= i or ...
  end
  product
end
```

Both generating an array with Fibonacci numbers and calculating the product can be done [less verbose](http://ideone.com/nzF4uD).